# Rate exceeded in throttling is thrown on DescribeJobFlows

Tags: amazon-web-services, throttling

Several days ago all went well, but now, not just one, but three of our servers are throwing these exceptions:

`{
  "Error" => {
    "Message" => "Rate exceeded",
    "Code" => "Throttling",
    "Type" => "Sender"
  }
}`

This happens when retrieving data from Amazon, while calling `DescribeJobFlows` on `Amazon::Coral::ElasticMapReduceClient`, and shows as NFO Exception Retriable invalid response.

Comment: You must be hitting the server too hard it looks like. Try these links with suggestions or other information and then please let us know what works for you. http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxKR75VKOYDS60/How-to-handle-a-quot-Throttling-Maximum-sending-rate-exceeded-quot-error https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=366822#

Comment: Thank you very much.Now ,I have know the reason without the links.My colleages told me .Thanks any way.The reason is that there are so many  tasks.We have 5 servers and aws must receive our data during 5 hours.But it is not enough to upload one server task to AWS in an hour.So time is out. I will read the links and then tell u which one can solve my problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Every AWS API has dynamic throttling protection. 
It's kinda sad but best way it to retry/sleep between API calls :(

There is a [configuration for the boto3 client to change `max_retries`](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/config.html) before throwing the exception. There is also the [general reference on how to use retries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should add some retry logic to your code. See this other Stackoverflow question for some ways of implementing that in Python:

[Need advice to add exponenital back-off logic in AWS API in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463774/need-advice-to-add-exponenital-back-off-logic-in-aws-api-in-python)